# How to implement contacts filter in android phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, android-contacts

I have an option to send text message in my application. So there is a text box to enter a mobile number. I need to dynamically populate the filtered contacts if user entering the number. I just need similar to mobile phone contact search criteria. i.e, If user types 998 I need to display the list of filtered contacts based on given input 998.

To do this I have used  `navigator.contacts.find()`, using this method I am able to get and find particular contacts. But not dynamic search criteria.

This is my text box,

```
 <input name="" id="numberTxt" placeholder="Enter A Mobile Number" value=""  type="tel" data-mini="true">
```

If user typing any number while typing I need to display filtered numbers. Is this possible? If yes, How can I do that? Any additional plugin are require? Any suggestions,

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter = "";         
    options.multiple = true;     
    filter = ["displayName", "name"]; 
    navigator.contacts.find(filter, onSuccess, onError, options);
}

function onSuccess(contacts) {
       for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
            console.log("Display Name = " + contacts[i].displayName);
        }
}

function onError(contactError) {
     alert('onError!');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have installed the Contact Picker plugin from the following link,https://github.com/hazemhagrass/ContactPicker.git and modified the code code to little extent like,

```
window.plugins.ContactPicker.chooseContact(function(contactInfo) {
        var contactNumber = contactInfo.mobileNumber;
        document.getElementById("numberTxt").value= contactNumber ;
    });
```

I have added the `mobileNumber` parameter to `contactInfo` object so that I able to get any contact number from contact book and used in HTML.

ContactPicker.js modified code,

```
cordova.exec(function(contactInfo) {
        newContantInfo = {
            displayName: contactInfo.displayName,
            email: contactInfo.email,
            mobileNumber:contactInfo.mobileNumber, //included the mobile Number parameter
            phones: []
        };
        for (var i in contactInfo.phones) {
            if (contactInfo.phones[i].length)
            newContantInfo.phones = newContantInfo.phones.concat(contactInfo.phones[i]);
        };
        success(newContantInfo);
    }, failure, "ContactPicker", "chooseContact", []);
```

In ContactPickerPlugin.java,

```
 contact.put("email", email);
    contact.put("displayName", name);
    contact.put("mobileNumber", mobileNumber); // included the mobile Number in contact object
    contact.put("phones", phones);
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you can filter by phone numbers.  You need to be sure the "phoneNumbers" field name is listed in your array of fields to filter by.  Below is an example I tested on Android to filter by phone number.

```
document.getElementById('searchContactsButton').onclick = function(e){
          var options = new ContactFindOptions();
          options.filter = document.getElementById('searchInput').value;
          options.multiple = true;
          var fieldsToFilter = ["phoneNumbers"];
          navigator.contacts.find(fieldsToFilter, 
            function(contacts) {
                alert('found ' + contacts.length + ' contacts');
          }, function(contactError) {
                alert('error: ' + contactError);
          }, options);
        }
```

Comment: I don't need to check whether the contact is exist or not. On key press while typing the mobile number I need to display the matched patterns. Like If I type 998 it should automatically display the contacts which has 998 number. How should I do that? Any idea
?

Comment: You could try adding an event handler to the input element and listen for 'change' or 'input' events.  Thereby, firing your function that would filter the contacts on the device.